# why soap web services

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

whats the real reason behind using soap to pass values between web-service and client application ? Why cant we use XML ? What advantages does soap give over XML?

Comment: @skaffman +1 - This one almost makes me wish there was an "RTFM" option under "close".

Comment: -1 because SOAP is XML - and one should stumble over this fact the moment one reads about SOAP. Try rephrase or concretize your question.

Comment: Because of the edit, there's no way of knowing the naiveté of this question, but these comments are what I hate about SO. "SOAP is XML" is a false statement. SOAP USES XML to format it's data AND additional metadata. One could transmit simple XML from a webservice without using the SOAP protocol. Whether that would be advisable is debatable, but such simple comment statements and downvoting isn't helpful.. and being helpful is what this site is about, not ganging up on newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soap uses XML as its message format, you can look [at the example below](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Sample_SOAP_message). The advantage over plain XML messages is, that you have a spec, which defines, how you construct calls to remote services (which was a revolution many years ago). Over the years, a competing approach, namely [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) has gained more traction in this space, not least because the SOAP has [some](http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.infosystems.www.misc/SOAP.html) [shortcomings](http://www.taranfx.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol).

```
POST /InStock HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 299

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetStockPrice xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
      <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
    </m:GetStockPrice>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

> SOAP, originally defined as Simple
>   Object Access Protocol, is a protocol
>   specification for exchanging
>   structured information in the
>   implementation of Web Services in
>   computer networks. **It relies on**
>    **Extensible Markup Language (XML)** for
>   its message format.

[WIKI SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)